# Why does my javascript code not make the display for "unselected" div element to "none?"

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you select the "tv" option, it displays a div, and if you select the "cooker" options, it displays a different div. I want to make it so when one option is selected, the prior div elements have their display become "none."

I've tried making it so when a value is selected, it's display is equal to block and I made an array to make the other div element displays to "none." My code doesn't work though.

Thank you to anyone that helps.

```js
const tvContainer=document.getElementsByClassName("tv-options-container")[0];
const applianceType=document.getElementById("appliance-type");
// const applianceOptions=document.querySelectorAll(".appliance-type.option");
const opTest=document.querySelectorAll("appliance-type.option");
var selectedApp=null;

var optionsArr=[];
 
var values = Array.from(document.getElementById("appliance-type").options).map(e => e.value);
optionsArr.append(values);
 

  function show(value_){
         document.getElementById(value_).style.display="block";
 
    for(let i=0;i<optionsArr.length;i++){
       
         if(optionsArr[i]!=value_){
            document.getElementById(optionsArr[i]).style.display="none";
        }
     }
// selectedApp=applianceType.value;
 
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
}
.options {
  height: 30px;
  -moz-appearance: none; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
  appearance: none;
  padding-right: 1.25em;
  padding-left: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='10px' width='15px'%3E%3Ctext x='0' y='11' fill='lightblue'%3E%E2%96%BE%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1.5em 1em;
  background-position: right center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tv-options-container,
.cooker-options-container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Add appliance</h1>
  <p>Please provide the details for the appliance</p>
  <form action="">
    <fieldset style="border: none">
      <label for="appliance-type">Appliance type:</label>
      <select onchange="show(value)" class="options" name="appliance-type" id="appliance-type">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose appliance</option>
        <option value="tv">TV</option>
        <option value="cooker">Cooker</option>
      </select>
      <!-- style="display:none;"  -->
      <div class="tv-options-container" id="tv">
        <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer: &#160;</label>
        <select class="options" name="tv-manufacturer" id="tv-manufacturer">
          <option value="" selected disabled></option>
          <option value="narkasse">Narkasse</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <label for="model-name">Model Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="model-name" id="model-name" />
        <br />
        <hr />
        <label for="">Display Type</label>
        <select class="option" name="" id="">
          <option value="" selected disabled></option>
          <option value="display-type">LED</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="cooker-options-container" style="display: none" id="cooker">
        <p>cooker</p>
        <p>cooker</p>
        <p>cooker</p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: You are almost there! your `optionsArray` consists of empty string. You need to take care of that as well as your list of options has a empty option. 
Also, its best to directly save the list of values into `optionsArray` instead of 
 using .append. `.append` is a function for a element not an array function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a great job!! There are just two things to take care of:

1. Your options array consists of `""`
   Hence, add a condition check if the value is not `""`. Something like:
   `if(optionsArr[i] && optionsArr[i]!=value_){`
2. Directly save the values in optionsArr

```js
const tvContainer=document.getElementsByClassName("tv-options-container")[0];
const applianceType=document.getElementById("appliance-type");
// const applianceOptions=document.querySelectorAll(".appliance-type.option");
const opTest=document.querySelectorAll("appliance-type.option");
var selectedApp=null;

var optionsArr = Array.from(document.getElementById("appliance-type").options).map(e => e.value);

 

  function show(value_){
         document.getElementById(value_).style.display="block";
 
    for(let i=0;i<optionsArr.length;i++){
       
         if(optionsArr[i] && optionsArr[i]!=value_){
            document.getElementById(optionsArr[i]).style.display="none";
        }
     }
// selectedApp=applianceType.value;
 
}
```

```css
*{
        box-sizing: border-box;
     
    }
    fieldset{
        padding: 0;
    }
    .options{
        height:30px;
        -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
    appearance:none; 
    padding-right: 1.25EM;
    padding-left: 0.25EM;
border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='10px' width='15px'%3E%3Ctext x='0' y='11' fill='lightblue'%3E%E2%96%BE%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.5EM 1EM;
    background-position: right center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    
    .tv-options-container, .cooker-options-container{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Add appliance</h1>
        <p>Please provide the details for the appliance</p>
        <form action="">
            <fieldset style="border:none">
                <label for="appliance-type">Appliance type:</label>
                <select onchange="show(value)" class="options" name="appliance-type" id="appliance-type">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose appliance</option>
                    <option value="tv">TV</option>
                    <option value="cooker">Cooker</option>
                </select>
                <!-- style="display:none;"  -->
                <div class="tv-options-container" id="tv">
                    <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer: &#160;</label>
                    <select class="options" name="tv-manufacturer" id="tv-manufacturer">
                        <option value="" selected disabled> </option>
                        <option value="narkasse">Narkasse </option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label for="model-name">Model Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="model-name" id="model-name">
                    <br>
                    <hr>
                    <label for="">Display Type</label>
                    <select class="option" name="" id="">
                        <option value="" selected disabled> </option>
                        <option value="display-type">LED</option>
                    </select>

                </div>



                <div class="cooker-options-container" style="display:none;" id="cooker">
                    <p>cooker</p>
                    <p>cooker</p>
                    <p>cooker</p>

                </div>




            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js code seems a bit complexed,since there are just two options in the `select` component,we can use below code to simplify it

```
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div[class*='-options-container']" )
function show(value){
  if(value === 'tv'){
   divs[0].style.display = "block";
   divs[1].style.display = "none";
  }else{
   divs[1].style.display = "block";
   divs[0].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

If there are multiple options,then we need to iterate them first,to make each of them `display` to `none`,then change the current element `display` to `block`

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div[class*='-options-container']" )
function show(value){
  if(value === 'tv'){
   divs[0].style.display = "block";
   divs[1].style.display = "none";
  }else{
   divs[1].style.display = "block";
   divs[0].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
*{
        box-sizing: border-box;
     
    }
    fieldset{
        padding: 0;
    }
    .options{
        height:30px;
        -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
    appearance:none; 
    padding-right: 1.25EM;
    padding-left: 0.25EM;
border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='10px' width='15px'%3E%3Ctext x='0' y='11' fill='lightblue'%3E%E2%96%BE%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.5EM 1EM;
    background-position: right center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    
    .tv-options-container, .cooker-options-container{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Add appliance</h1>
        <p>Please provide the details for the appliance</p>
        <form action="">
            <fieldset style="border:none">
                <label for="appliance-type">Appliance type:</label>
                <select onchange="show(value)" class="options" name="appliance-type" id="appliance-type">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose appliance</option>
                    <option value="tv">TV</option>
                    <option value="cooker">Cooker</option>
                </select>
                <!-- style="display:none;"  -->
                <div class="tv-options-container" id="tv">
                    <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer: &#160;</label>
                    <select class="options" name="tv-manufacturer" id="tv-manufacturer">
                        <option value="" selected disabled> </option>
                        <option value="narkasse">Narkasse </option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label for="model-name">Model Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="model-name" id="model-name">
                    <br>
                    <hr>
                    <label for="">Display Type</label>
                    <select class="option" name="" id="">
                        <option value="" selected disabled> </option>
                        <option value="display-type">LED</option>
                    </select>

                </div>



                <div class="cooker-options-container" style="display:none;" id="cooker">
                    <p>cooker</p>
                    <p>cooker</p>
                    <p>cooker</p>

                </div>




            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </main>
</body>

</html>
```